# Wait to zip files before deleting them

Tags: powershell

I use a zip function to zip my files before deleting them, however the delete function is getting called before the zip has finished therefore I am losing data.

How I call the functions:

```
gi $archiveMonthFolder | out-zip $auditDir$zipFolderName.zip $_

#Delete any file in the archive folder
deleteFiles $sourceArchiveDir
```

My functions:

```
function out-zip {
  $path = $args[0]
  $files = $input

  if (-not $path.EndsWith('.zip')) {$path += '.zip'} 

  if (-not (test-path $path)) {
    set-content $path ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
  } 

  $ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($path) 
  $files | foreach {$zipfile.CopyHere($_.fullname)} 
}

function deleteFiles{
  # The parameter. 
  param([string]$sourceDir) 

  #Delete the files
  Remove-Item -Path "$sourceDir\*" -Recurse
}
```

I tried to use the `| out-null` however this had the same effect.

Comment: It is because you are using the Namespace method to zip the files. When calling the CopyHere method processing does not wait for completion before proceeding. You will find many examples of this. You could either put in an arbitrary Sleep or consider using an alternate command line zip like 7Zip. Or you could create a job like http://serverfault.com/questions/448728/powershell-wait-for-compressing-to-finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend installing the .Net Framework 4.5 (if you haven't already) and use its [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. The [`CreateFromDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method runs synchronously, meaning it returns only after the operation completed, so you can simply run the deletion afterwards:

```psh
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')

$src = 'C:\source\folder'
$zip = 'C:\path\to\your.zip'

[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($src, $zip, 'Optimal', $false)

Remove-Item -Path "$src\*" -Recurse
```

Replace `$false` with `$true` if you don't want the parent folder removed from the zipped paths.

Answer (score 0):

I hope a check of the ZIP file existance before the delete call may be helpful as below:

```
gi $archiveMonthFolder | out-zip $auditDir$zipFolderName.zip $_

#Delete any file in the archive folder
do
{
     Start-Sleep -s 10
}while ((Test-Path $auditDir$zipFolderName.zip) -eq $false)

deleteFiles $sourceArchiveDir
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[wait process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849813.aspx)" command.

I hope this code snippet will help you.

```
$ZipId = (get-process 7zFM).id
if($ZipId)
{
    wait-process -id $ZipId    
    Write-host "Zipper is closed, now delete the file and wash your hands"

}
else
{
    Write-host "No zipper found, Im not even sure i have pants... Move along"
}
```